# Python retrieving windows service information

Tags: python, windows, windows-services

Can python retrieve the name of the user that owns a windows service?

I've had a fiddle with win32serviceutil but to no avail, nor can I find much documentation on it beyond starting and stopping services.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted, I had the service run a python script with win32api.GetUserName() as it's output.